# How do I compare random numbers to input numbers?

Tags: java, arrays

I have generated five numbers and let input from user to guess the five numbers. I am having trouble comparing the values to check if the user has guessed right (lottery). I want to compare each individual number to the random numbers. So if the winning numbers were 23, 32 43, 54, 65
and user guessed 54, 53, 22, 33 44. Then there would be a specific output and if the user guessed two numbers correctly then there would be a different ouput and so on.

I was thinking if else statements, but not sure how to start, especially because I dont know how to compare the five random numbers to specific user input values

Here is what I have:

````
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Lotterygame
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
   int firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit, fourthDigit, fifthDigit;
   int match, nomatch;
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Random random = new Random();
        int[] numbers = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            numbers[i] = random.nextInt(100);
        }

System.out.println("Enter a first digit");
       firstDigit = input.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter a second digit");
       secondDigit = input.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter a third digit");
        thirdDigit = input.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter a fourth digit");
       fourthDigit = input.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter a fifth digit");
      fifthDigit = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("The winning numbers are: ");        
        for (int number : numbers) {
            System.out.print(" " + number);
        }
         
System.out.println("\nYour number are: " + firstDigit + " " + secondDigit + " " + thirdDigit + " " + fourthDigit + " " + fifthDigit); ```
````

Comment: I'd put `firstDigit` to `fifthDigit` also in a `int[] digits = new int[5]` array (like `numbers`). Then you can straightforward do a nested loop, where you compare each value from the `numbers` array with the `digits` array and count how many hits you have

Comment: Another possibility is, that at each input of a number you iterate over the `numbers` array and check if your current input number is contained ...

Comment: Furthermore you probably should take care of, that neither the inputs nor the random numbers can be duplicates ...

Comment: I added another array for digits, but unsure how to compare each values. Ive tried multiple times and  keep getting errors - int[] cannot be converted to int and int cannot be converted to boolean.

Comment: A clarifying question is, how would I go on to writing "You won $10" if the user guessed one of the five matches? and so on if the user guessed more with an increase in money? - (Thank you for your previous help)

Answer (score 2):

> *"... So if the winning numbers were 23, 32 43, 54, 65 and user guessed 54, 53, 22, 33 44. Then there would be a specific output and if the user guessed two numbers correctly then there would be a different ouput and so on.
>
>
>
> I was thinking if else statements, but not sure how to start, especially because I dont know how to compare the five random numbers to specific user input values ..."*

Start by containing the data.  An *[array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)*, for each set, should suffice.
I'm using an [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) *array*, rather than a *primitive* [`int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) *array*, as to utilize the [`Collections#shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) method.
This will produce a set of unique values.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int i, n = 5;
Integer[] R = new Integer[99], G = new Integer[n];
for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) R[i - 1] = i;
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(R));
R = Arrays.copyOfRange(R, 0, n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    out.printf("guess %d:  ", i + 1);
    G[i] = in.nextInt();
}
```

From here, traverse *G*, and sub-traverse *R*, qualifying any matching numbers.
You could even use another *array*, or a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html), to contain the values.
Although, since you're only printing the values, a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class would be a simpler approach.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for (int g : G)
    for (int r : R)
        if (g == r) {
            if (!s.isEmpty()) s.append(", ");
            s.append(g);
        }
out.println("R = " + Arrays.toString(R));
out.println("G = " + Arrays.toString(G));
out.println("matching numbers:  " + s);
```

Here is an example usage.

```
guess 1:  55
guess 2:  24
guess 3:  93
guess 4:  1
guess 5:  2
R = [50, 24, 78, 55, 93]
G = [55, 24, 93, 1, 2]
matching numbers:  55, 24, 93
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, imo, is to use a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet()).  Sets cannot hold duplicates so it would be perfect for lottery numbers.

- One set has the winning numbers.
- The other set has the users choices.
- using the [retainAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method only keeps the user numbers that were the same as the winningNumbers.

```
static int NCHOICES = 5;
Set<Integer> winningNumber = new HashSet<>(Set.of(23, 32, 43, 54, 65));
Set<Integer> user = new HashSet<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 1; i <= NCHOICES; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Please enter #%d: ", i);
    int numb = input.nextInt();
    if (numb > LIMIT || !user.add(numb)) {
        System.out.printf("Number %d already added or too large, try again.%n", numb);
        i--;
    }
}
user.retainAll(winningNumber);
System.out.printf("The user picked %d correctly%n", user.size());
System.out.printf("They are %s%n", user);
```

If this input were `41, 23, 62, 4, 32`, the output would be

```
Please enter #1: 41
Please enter #2: 23
Please enter #3: 62
Please enter #4: 4
Please enter #5: 32
The user picked 2 correctly
They are [32, 23]
```

To populate the `winningNUmbers` set, you can do it as follows.

- define a size LIMIT of the number to be chosen.
- Allocate an `ArrayList` to hold the numbers from 1 to LIMIT.
- then populate the list using a loop.
- then each time you want to create a net set of winning numbers.

  - clear the existing `winningNumber` set.
  - Shuffle the list.
  - And add a `sublist` of the first `NCHOICES` numbers to the set.

```
static int LIMIT = 100;
List<Integer> lotteryNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < LIMIT; i++) {
    lotteryNumbers.add(i);
}
winningNumbers.clear();
Collections.shuffle(lotteryNumbers);
winningNumbers.addAll(lotteryNumbers.subList(0,NCHOICES));
System.out.println(winningNumbers);
```

prints something like

```
[49, 34, 54, 39, 57]
```

Note that you only need to create the List of numbers once.  Just shuffle it each time right before you want to populate the winningNumbers set.